# A question on advanced algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let be $\mathbb{R^*}$ and $\mathbb{C^*}$ the multiplicative groups of non-zero real numbers and non-zero complex numbers respectively. Is $\operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{Z_6},\mathbb{R^*}\oplus\mathbb{C^*})\cong\mathbb{Z_6}\oplus \mathbb{Z_2}? $ Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ into any group $G$ is the same as an element $g \in G$ such that $g^6$ is the identity element of $G$ (look at where $1 \in \mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ goes). Can you write down the elements of $\mathbb{R}^{\times} \oplus \mathbb{C}^{\times}$ with this property?